# maven-publish plugin vs artifactory gradle plugin

Tags: maven, artifactory

I'm fairly new to gradle, and I'm using artifactory as my repo server. I looked online on how to publish my project to my repo server and found that I could use maven-publish or use the artifactory gradle plugin. What advantages are there in using the artifactory gradle plugin instead of the maven-publish plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the Artifactory Gradle plugin you are utilizing the full power of Artifactory metadata. Your artifacts will be annotated with the information about the build: which artifacts were built, which dependencies were used, the environment variables of the build, etc. etc.

This information is critical, available only at build time, and if you opt to deploy without the plugin you will loose this information forever.

More details in [the official docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration).

---

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) and [[artifactory]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artifactory), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) for details and links.</sup>